# Place field in "Url Alias" advanced group section (path-0)

Tags: forms, hooks, 9

I'm trying to place my node field to the Advanced group - URL alias section.
I'm doing it in custom hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter(), where I'm trying to set custom #group like this:

```
$form['my_filed']['#group'] = 'path-0';
```

But "path-0" neither "path_0", "path" works. But if I use something else e.g. "meta", "menu" ... then my field is displayed in right place.
What's the trick to place it in "Url Alias"?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried playing with the module's weight? I've seen something like this before where my custom module's hook is running before that group even exists. If you increase the module's weight, you can ensure it runs after the group is created.

Comment: Actually yes. My module has weight 1002 - and is last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not all that obvious unless you look at the code which processes the form, but you can use the `][` separator, which the general form API uses to denote a parent/child relationship in a string.

This works for me:

```
$form['field_foo']['#group'] = 'path][0';
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks @Clive.